# Fourier transform of Log[RealAbs[x]]^2

Tags: fourier-analysis, integral-transforms

At least one of the outputs (highly likely both)

```
FourierTransform[Log[RealAbs[x]]^2, x, s]
(*(Sqrt[2 π] (EulerGamma + Log[Abs[s]]))/Abs[s]*)
InverseFourierTransform[%, s, x]
(*-EulerGamma^2 - π^2/12 + Log[Abs[x]]^2*)
```

is not correct since the `Log[RealAbs[x]]^2` should be returned by [`InverseFourierTransform`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InverseFourierTransform.html) up to the documentation. Because the integral

```
Integrate[Log[RealAbs[x]]^2, {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
*Integrate::idiv: Integral of Log[RealAbs[x]]^2 does not converge on {-∞,∞}.*
```

diverges, the Fourier transform of `Log[RealAbs[x]]^2` does not exist in the traditional sense (see [Encyclopedia of Mathematics](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Fourier_transform)). I also don't find it in the math literature. Can somebody kindly explain that?

PS. The command `FourierTransform[Log[Abs[x]]^2, x, s]` also performs `(Sqrt[2 \ [Pi]] (EulerGamma + Log[Abs[s]]))/Abs[s]`.

Comment: Please check your code, it doesn't evaluate!

Comment: @Ulrich Neumann: Thank you. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, perhaps a little step forward:

The simplified problem (without `^2`) evaluates as expected ((see 317 in en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform) ) if you substitude `RealAbs` by `Abs`

```
FourierTransform[Log[ Abs[x]]  , x, s]
(*-(Sqrt[(\[Pi]/2)]/Abs[s]) - EulerGamma Sqrt[2\[Pi]] DiracDelta[s] *)
InverseFourierTransform[%, s, x]
(*Log[Abs[x]]*)
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest to the question. The Fourier transform   of Log[ Abs[x]] does not exist in the traditional sense because the integral $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty |\log|x||\,dx$$ diverges. The same question arises: how is it made? Wiki (see  317  in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform) confirms it, referring to Erdélyi, Arthur, ed. (1954), Tables of Integral Transforms, Vol 1 and Kammler, David (2000), A First Course in Fourier Analysis, However, I find it in neither the former nor  the latter. Also FourierTransform[Log[RealAbs[x]], x, s] gives  -(Sqrt[(\[Pi]/2)]/Abs[s]).

Comment: That's ok , but Mathematica v12 evaluates ` InverseFourierTransform[FourierTransform[Log[RealAbs[x]], x, s], s, x]` to `EulerGamma + Log[Abs[x]]`

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your " That's ok" . Can you elaborate your comment in details? TIA

Comment: That means, you are right with your statement "FourierTransform[Log[RealAbs[x]], x, s] gives -(Sqrt[([Pi]/2)]/Abs[s])" . Using `Abs[]` instead gives the same transformation pair which you found in "(see 317 in en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform) "

Comment: I repeat I don't find 317 from Wiki in the references (screens on demand through Dropbox). Hope I am clear.

Comment: @user Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2340049/58219 https://mathoverflow.net/a/300037/108919

Comment: @xzczd: Thank you. The definition $ \hat{\phi}(t)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\phi(x)e^{-ixt}dx$  used there differs from the definition of the Fourier transform used in Mathematica.